# SVG feTurbulence overflows

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to reproduce a metal effect on a svg rect.
To achieve my intent used the following filter:

```
<filter id='noiseFilter'>
   <feTurbulence type='fractalNoise' baseFrequency='1' numOctaves='1' stitchTiles='stitch' />
</filter>


<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" opacity="0.14" filter="url(#noiseFilter)" />
```

The effect is perfect, I like it. But I noticed that the filter goes outside the rect.

You can see the same issue in this svg:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3C!-- svg: first layer --%3E%0A%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 250 250' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%0A  %3Cfilter id='noiseFilter'%3E%0A    %3CfeTurbulence %0A      type='fractalNoise' %0A      baseFrequency='0.65' %0A      numOctaves='3' %0A      stitchTiles='stitch'/%3E%0A  %3C/filter%3E%0A  %0A  %3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' filter='url(%23noiseFilter)'/%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E
```

Infact, if you inspect the svg, you can notice that the texture overflows the rect:
[image]

It is possible to avoi the overflow?

Thanks a lot